# Unable to resolve the server's DNS address

Tags: html, dns, server

I get this message - 'Unable to resolve the server's DNS address' when I try to use this code

```
<div class = "video">
    <!-- vid here -->
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/145884101?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="900" height="550" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

</div>
```

Comment: Looks ok and works fine for me...

Comment: Same, just tested on JSFiddle on Chrome and works perfectly.

Comment: You will get this kind of errors when ISP can't find server or the the server is blocked by ISP. Try changing your DNS to free DNS servers

Answer (score -1):

> The code works perfectly.

The only possible reason must be that your device is unable to access the URL due to some ***ISP restrictions***

Try running the same code from a different device, possibly working on a different ISP.

Alternatively, your device's Firewall or Anti-Virus Program might be blocking your connection.

Hope this helps. :)